# python 2.7 why is this not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn `python`, but for some reason this is not working:

```
xxx = ['dd''ddss''dsAAS']:
for z in xxx:
    print (xxx, blaa blaa)
```

Gives following error:

```
File "/home/dux/untitled1.py", line 9
    xxx = ['dd''ddss''dsAAS']:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what is the point of z? for z in xxx? is there anything that can be done with z?

Answer (score 2):

```
xxx = ['dd''ddss''dsAAS']:
```

Trailing `:` is a syntax error here, as indicated in the traceback (see the `^` character pointing to the exact location of the problem).  You probably wanted:

```
xxx = ['dd', 'ddss', 'dsAAS']
```

Answer (score 0):

The : is for opening structures. Also you have to separate the elements with ,

```
xxx = ['dd', 'ddss', 'dsAAS']
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ?

this?

```
     xxx = ['dd''ddss''dsAAS']
```

No colon at the end. Then

```
     for z in xxx: 
         print z
```

Comment: what the point of z? is there anything advance you can do with it? or is it just how for loops are written?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do. It looks like z in this case is for iterating through your list/array.
Its basically saying:
For every element in the 'xxx' list print that element. But it doesnt have to be called z. You could call it whatever you want. Its just a placeholder.
But once again the point of z is dependent on what you are trying to do.